# Refreshing the form I created with angular reactive form

Tags: c#, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I create inputs to receive answers as many as the number of questions from sql.

I want to do: if

**1-) the question has just been answered, add it to the database.**

**2-) If there is no change in the question, do not take action.**

**3-) If the question was removed later, delete it from the database.**

(( answerValue=ture ) if question was answered - ((answerValue=false if question was later removed))

These are the ones I tried. probably many method errors. What is the most correct method?

Finally, I want to show the updated version of the form with the database on the page!

I've tried many things and I've been dealing with this problem for a few days but I haven't been able to solve it yet. I'm trying to learn Angular and C#. Thank you very much for your help. I can understand better if you explain with an example.

**getAnamnezAnswersByPatientId(connectId: number)** i get the answer list

**getAnamnezQuestion()**  I'm getting the questions

```
  let foundAdd = value.answers.filter((res: any) => {return res.answerValue == true && res.id == null;});
let foundUpdate = value.answers.filter((res: any) => {return res.id != null && res.answerValue == true;});
let foundRemove = value.answers.filter((res: any) => { return res.answerValue == false && res.id != null;});
```

foundAdd: add new record to database.

foundUpdate: update existing record

foundRemove: delete existing record
`

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getAnamnezAnswersByPatientId(this.patient.connectId)
      .then((res) => {
        return this.getAnamnezQuestion().then((res) => {
          return this.pushAnswerInput();
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (this.errCount < 5) {
          this.ngOnInit();
          this.errCount++;
          console.log('Error: #' + this.errCount + ' ' + err);
        } else {
          console.log('5 deneme yapıldı hata aşılamadı. Sayfayı yenileyin.');
        }
      });

    this.anamnezForm = this.fb.group({
      patientId: this.patient.id,
      connectId: this.patient.connectId,
      answers: this.fb.array([]),
    });
  }

  getAnamnezAnswersByPatientId(connectId: number) { 

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.clientService
        .getAnamnezAnswersByPatientId(connectId)
        .subscribe((res: any) => {
          this.PatientAnamnezAnswers = res.data.answers;
          resolve('Ok');
        });
    });
  }

  getAnamnezQuestion() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.clientService.getAnamnezQuestion().subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.anamnezQuestion = res.data;
        resolve('Ok');
      });
    });
  }

  pushAnswerInput() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.anamnezQuestion.map((x: any) => {
        this.answers().push(this.newAnswers(x.id));
        resolve('Ok');
      });
    });
  }

  newAnswers(questionId: number): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      id: this.createAnswersId(questionId),
      connectId: new FormControl(this.patient.connectId),
      patientId: new FormControl(this.patient.id),
      createDate: new FormControl(new Date()),
      updateDate: new FormControl(new Date()), // UPDATE DATE AYARLANACAK
      questionId: new FormControl(questionId),
      answerValue: this.createAnswersValue(questionId),
      answer: this.createAnswers(questionId),
    });
  }

  createAnswersId(questionId: number): FormControl {
    if (
      this.PatientAnamnezAnswers.find((element: any) => {
        return element.questionId == questionId;
      })
    ) {
      var result = this.PatientAnamnezAnswers.find(function (element) {
        return element.questionId == questionId;
      });
      return new FormControl(result.id);
    } else {
      return new FormControl(null);
    }
  }

  createAnswers(questionId: number): FormControl {
    if (
      this.PatientAnamnezAnswers.find((element: any) => {
        return element.questionId == questionId;
      })
    ) {
      var result = this.PatientAnamnezAnswers.find(function (element) {
        return element.questionId == questionId;
      });
      return new FormControl({
        value: result.answer,
        disabled: !result.answerValue,
      });
    } else {
      return new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true });
    }
  }

  createAnswersValue(questionId: number): FormControl {
    if (
      this.PatientAnamnezAnswers.find((element: any) => {
        return element.questionId == questionId;
      })
    ) {
      var result = this.PatientAnamnezAnswers.find(function (element) {
        return element.questionId == questionId;
      });
      return new FormControl(result.answerValue);
    } else {
      return new FormControl(false);
    }
  }

  answers(): FormArray {
    return this.anamnezForm.get('answers') as FormArray;
  }

  changeShowInput(event: any) {
    // console.log(this.anamnezForm.get('answers').value[event].enable())

    //this.answers().get([event]).disable()
    let value = this.answers().get([event]).get('answerValue').value;
    if (value) {
      this.answers().get([event]).get('answer').enable();
    } else {
      this.answers().get([event]).get('answer').disable();
      this.answers().get([event]).get('answer').reset();
    }
  }


  onFormSubmit(value: any) {



    let foundAdd = value.answers.filter((res: any) => {return res.answerValue == true && res.id == null;});
    let foundUpdate = value.answers.filter((res: any) => {return res.id != null && res.answerValue == true;});
    let foundRemove = value.answers.filter((res: any) => { return res.answerValue == false && res.id != null;});


    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{

    
      if (foundAdd.length > 0) {
        let valueAdd = new AnamnezConnectModel() 
        valueAdd.connectId = this.patient.connectId;
        valueAdd.patientId = this.patient.id;  
        valueAdd.answers = foundAdd;
        this.clientService.addAnamnezAnswer(valueAdd).subscribe((res) => {});
        resolve('ok');
      }
  
     
      
      if (foundUpdate.length > 0) {
        let valueUpdate = new AnamnezConnectModel()
        valueUpdate.connectId = this.patient.connectId;
        valueUpdate.patientId = this.patient.id;  
        valueUpdate.answers = foundUpdate;
      
        this.clientService.updateAnamnezAnswer(valueUpdate).subscribe((res) => {});
        resolve('ok');
      }
  

      if (foundRemove.length > 0) {
        let valueRemove = new AnamnezConnectModel() 
        valueRemove.connectId = this.patient.connectId;
        valueRemove.patientId = this.patient.id; 
        valueRemove.answers = foundRemove;
        this.clientService.deleteAnamnezAnswer(valueRemove).subscribe((res) => {});
        resolve('ok');
      }


    }).then(res=> this.ngOnInit()).catch((err)=> {
      console.log(err)
    })
  



  }



  
  get anamnezFormGroup() {
    return (<FormArray>this.anamnezForm.get('answers')) as FormArray;
  }
}
```

`

`

```
<form [formGroup]="anamnezForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit(anamnezForm.value)">
  <div formArrayName="answers">
    <div
      *ngFor="let item of anamnezFormGroup.controls; let i = index"
      [formGroupName]="i"
    >
      {{ anamnezQuestion[i].id }}. {{ anamnezQuestion[i].question }}

      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              aria-label="Checkbox for following text input"
              formControlName="answerValue"
              (change)="changeShowInput(i)"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          aria-label="Text input with checkbox"
          formControlName="answer"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button>Gönder</button>
</form>
```

`

It's technically working at this stage, but my database and form don't seem up-to-date because my form is not reactive. I have to manually refresh the page. (F5)

Comment: Is there a particular reason you create multiple promise and resolve them like `resolve('Ok');`?

Comment: No. I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: Actually, after the 3 functions (**foundAdd,foundUpdate,foundRemove**) are finished, I wanted the **ngOnInit()** method to be reloaded and thus the form to be refreshed. But I'm not sure the build is correct

Answer (score 0):

I will try to focus on the problems I see with your code. Nevertheless I advice you to take a deeper look into Promises and Observables again to fully understand how the work.

Code focused on:

```
onFormSubmit(value: any) {
    let foundAdd = value.answers.filter((res: any) => {return res.answerValue == true && res.id == null;});
    let foundUpdate = value.answers.filter((res: any) => {return res.id != null && res.answerValue == true;});
    let foundRemove = value.answers.filter((res: any) => { return res.answerValue == false && res.id != null;});

    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      if (foundAdd.length > 0) {
        let valueAdd = new AnamnezConnectModel() 
        valueAdd.connectId = this.patient.connectId;
        valueAdd.patientId = this.patient.id;  
        valueAdd.answers = foundAdd;
        this.clientService.addAnamnezAnswer(valueAdd).subscribe((res) => {});
        resolve('ok');
      }
      
      if (foundUpdate.length > 0) {
        let valueUpdate = new AnamnezConnectModel()
        valueUpdate.connectId = this.patient.connectId;
        valueUpdate.patientId = this.patient.id;  
        valueUpdate.answers = foundUpdate;
      
        this.clientService.updateAnamnezAnswer(valueUpdate).subscribe((res) => {});
        resolve('ok');
      }
  
      if (foundRemove.length > 0) {
        let valueRemove = new AnamnezConnectModel() 
        valueRemove.connectId = this.patient.connectId;
        valueRemove.patientId = this.patient.id; 
        valueRemove.answers = foundRemove;
        this.clientService.deleteAnamnezAnswer(valueRemove).subscribe((res) => {});
        resolve('ok');
      }

    }).then(res=> this.ngOnInit()).catch((err)=> {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
```

To be honest this code only works by accident, since you are already resolving the promise, but are not actually returning something, therefore your code will continue to run, even if the promise has been resolved already.

Nevertheless this is also the reason why you have to refresh the page to get updated data. This is the sequence your code is running currently:

1. `this.clientService.addAnamnezAnswer(...)` gets called asynchronously
2. the promise will be resolved by calling `resolve('ok')`
3. `.then(res=> this.ngOnInit())` is invoked.
4. Now `this.clientService.updateAnamnezAnswer(...)` and `this.clientService.deleteAnamnezAnswer(...)` get invoked (again asynchronously)
5. Your subscriptions will be called, which do not have any logic in it.

My suggestion:

1. get rid of all promises you don't need
2. use rxjs `forkJoin` operator to handle observables in parallel
3. Try to get rid of duplicate code

For a quick solution you can just reuse the existing logic (remove the promise) and add the following code after the data "construction". This will lead to your code waiting for all calls to be completed until `ngOnInit` will be invoked:

```
forkJoin([
  this.clientService.addAnamnezAnswer(valueAdd),
  this.clientService.updateAnamnezAnswer(valueUpdate),
  this.clientService.deleteAnamnezAnswer(valueRemove)
]).subscribe(this.ngOnInit)
```